# How to prevent the foundation 5.x top-bar from going width 100%

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Currently I'm trying to find a way to shrink the scope of the top-bar to something like what row would do by default (keeping the width fixed (ish) even when the viewport is a wide screen desktop)

I'm able to get this working w/ a simple div class row + div class large-12 columns wrapping the nav class top-bar but ... it seems like I should/could get this working without having to wrap it in this way. Can anyone help reduce the complexity of what I have below?

*note -the class my-custom-thing is used to keep the background color the same across the top (the same color top-bar sets essentially)

```
<div class="my-custom-thing">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <nav class="top-bar"></nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the properties of row as well as column you can go with it..Ex:`max-width of row:62.5 em` by default and `padding of columns`

It looks fine and i don't think it looks complex as well.

But if you are just having these classes for having control of width i suggest the below solution.

```css
.my-custom-thing .top-bar {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 62.5rem; 
      height:30px;
      background-color:#555;
      margin:0px auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="my-custom-thing">
      <nav class="top-bar"></nav>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't working at all? max-width didnt work?is it the alignment issue? because it must have floated left as default..give `margin:0px auto` to center align